# How do I upgrade to Lubuntu SaucySalamder?

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, lubuntu

I am using Lubuntu on a virtual machine and have many files on here. Months ago, I kept getting pop-ups which asked me to update to Lubuntu 13.10 (I believe it was 13.10) Saucy Salamander but I kept saying 'Remind me later'. Now, I can't apt-get install anything and I keep getting these type of errors:

```
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
```

This post (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2103751) suggested that I upgrade (I should upgrade to Lubuntu Saucy Salamander). I don't want to download anything from here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) because I am afraid I will lose all my important files. Instead, I kept waiting till I got that pop-up again asking if I want to upgrade but I never get that popup anymore. I tried restarting my VM but still no popup. I then tried starting up the Software Updater but it keeps giving me an error saying:

```
Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection.
```

even though I can access the internet with no problems.

I tried installing packages from Synaptic Package Manager but it also gave me the

```
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
```

errors. How do I upgrade to Lubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander? Or how do I get Lubuntu to send me that 'upgrade to Saucy Salamander' pop up again? The one time I want to get the popup, I'm not getting it anymore -.-.